# PostgreSQL and MONEY data type for currency values

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.3, floating-point, money

For a project, I created a table with a column `price MONEY NOT NULL` column. And I thought it would handle decimals properly, unlike a floating number (i.e. IEEE rounding issues), but I end up having values like `$9.94` (string) being returned from the database, instead of `9.94` (numeric). Having to manually manipulate the field value by removing the dollar sign is silly; is there a way to have a `MONEY` column without a currency sign?

If not, what's the best data type replacement to handle currency values?

Comment: I'd rather use an integer with an implied number of decimals.

Comment: The `MONEY` datatype in Postgres is for dollars only. ;)

Comment: @ypercube, So.... other currencies have no rounding issues? Besides, it seems it can be changed through the `LC_MONETARY` db variable.

Comment: I find `money` a rather useless datatype. `numeric` is much better and more flexible.

Comment: `MONEY` is a great datatype, in theory. It's stored as a 64bit binary integer with an implied, fixed number of decimals. This means that storage is conserved and operations are always as fast and exact as possible (to the specified decimal precision.) It's a pity you can't specify the precision on a column-by-column basis (such as `MONEY(2)` and `MONEY(4)`) and that by default it prints numbers in a silly way: `$1,200.00`

Answer (score 12, accepted):

What about this?

A money value can be cast to numeric without loss of precision. Conversion to other types could potentially lose precision, and must also be done in two stages:

```
SELECT '52093.89'::money::numeric::float8;
```

Source:
http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/datatype-money.html

Comment: I finally decided to create a `VIEW` for the table, to case the column into a plain `numeric`. This seems to work for now.

Comment: **Never** cast monetary values to/from floating point. You will lose precision and have subtle rounding errors.

Comment: @Tobia in order to avoid that, the conversion must be done in two steps: from money to numeric and then to float. More info about that in Postgres docs: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/static/datatype-money.html.